# Select Box with OptGroup

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am currently working on an application that has a select box with option groups associated to each item.  Essentially, the end goal would be a 'select box' equivalent of the following:

Buyers (optgroup)

---

- Jenny (option)
- Johnny (option)

Sellers (optgroup)

---

- Megan (option)
- Matthew (option)

My current code is partially working.  It creates the groups successfully.  If I use a span inside the option instead of data-binding directly, it produces a blank record for each item.  However, it will not show the option text and it will stop running if I try to bind it directly to the option.

Could you review my code and give me an idea of what might be causing the issue?

Here is a fiddle with my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/lkritchey/my3Kw/6/

Below is a copy of my JavaScript code and HTML:

JavaScript:

```
var UserGroup = function (group, users) {
    this.GroupName = group;
    this.Users = users;
};

var User = function (guid, fullName) {
    this.UserId = guid;
    this.FullName = fullName;
};

var userListViewModel = {
    groupList: ko.observableArray([]),
    singleUserList: ko.observableArray([])
};

function populateData() {
    var users1 = [new User(1, "Jenny"), new User(2, "Johnny")];
    var users2 = [new User(3, "Megan"), new User(4, "Matthew")];
    userListViewModel.groupList.push(
    new UserGroup("Buyers", users1));
    userListViewModel.groupList.push(
    new UserGroup("Sellers", users2));
}
populateData();
ko.applyBindings(userListViewModel);
```

HTML:

```
<div>
     <h2>List of users:</h2>

    <div data-bind="foreach: $root.groupList">
         <h4 data-bind="text: GroupName"></h4>

        <ul data-bind="foreach: Users">
            <li data-bind="text: UserId + '-' + FullName"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>Select a User</h2>
User:
    <select data-bind="foreach: $root.groupList">
        <optGroup data-bind="attr: {label: GroupName}, 
        foreach: User">
            <option> <span data-bind="text: FullName"></span>

            </option>
        </optGroup>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
     <h2>Select a User:</h2>
User:
    <select data-bind="foreach: $root.groupList">
        <optGroup data-bind="attr: {label: GroupName}, 
        foreach: User">
            <option data-bind="text: FullName, value: UserId"></option>
        </optGroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: For anyone interested in the working product, here is an updated fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/my3Kw/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change `User` to `Users` in:

```
<optGroup data-bind="attr: {label: GroupName}, foreach: Users">
```

Also, you have to realize that an `<option>` element cannot contain any other elements. You'll have to remain with:

```
<option data-bind="text: FullName, value: UserId"></option>
```

Comment: Thanks - I only put the elements in the option since the code directly binding to the options element didn't work...which apparently is due to my typo of forgetting the 's' in Users.  Appreciate you looking it over!